# How to make an A4 publication fit in a letter document for ArXiv

Tags: margins, arxiv, journal, documentclass

I have written a paper in A4 format (Springer Journal style) and need to submit it to ArXiv. However, ArXiv messes up with the margins of the file for some reason. According to their FAQ, it is probably because they expect the paper to be in letter format instead of A4. How can I generate a *letter* version of a paper that was intended for publication in A4?

The Springer template I am using specifies:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimum amount of changes you can make are:

```
% first, include letterpaper option when specifying the document class:
\documentclass[twocolumn,letterpaper]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

% and then, specify new margins with the geometry package:
\usepackage[left=3.4cm,right=3.4cm,bottom=3.5cm,top=3.4cm]{geometry}
```